# (done) Request to Reopen "What happens when HR is the source of harassment?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

The question [What happens when HR is the source of harassment?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/104314/what-happens-when-hr-is-the-source-of-harassment) was recently closed as being unclear. I honestly have no idea how this applies, as I think the problem is pretty clearly described.

I would like to request that the question be reopened.

Comment: 2 of the votes were for company-specific policies/legal, the last of which was mine. Only 3 were unclear.

Comment: I am torn on this question, but for me the problem was I just do not believe there is any attempt at an actual question so much as a question that is hypothetical what should he do "IF" he is in a situation is not an acceptable format for a question here.  Edit the question to bring inline with expectations and I suspect you can get some reopen votes.

Comment: It is open now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Reason is just the top reason. The question vague / hypothetical without specifics.  It is likely legal which is a reason for VTC.

According to the [tour](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour):

> Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include
>   details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to
>   do.

When I asked for clarification to try and bring the question into conformance the OP was argumentative with me.

Comment: What isn't clear? The OP is observing harassment from the HR Director and her staff. The OP is then asking who they should report the harassment to instead. That is not a legal question.

Comment: @DavidK Not going to argue with you.  Clear is not the guideline and it is not clear to me. Observe with generalities is not consistent with tour guidelines.  You asked a question and got an answer.

Comment: @DavidK I also thought this was overly vague and I got the impression that it was actually a hypothetical question designed to stir up yet another gender discrimination discussion. But that could just be the OP trying to avoid being too specific.